# why windows service can't access file login screen?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have developed windows service in C#.NET, now when user restart the computer, service started automaticly in windows welcome (login) page, when service is started, it should create a folder in c: drive if it is not available or not created before, now the problem its not creating this folder !

I tried to stop and start the service after I login to my account, everything works fine and folder is created ! but if I stop the service and deleted the folder and restart the computer, the service couldn't create a folder in welcome login page when the service is start automaticly.

Comment: Show us the code.  And why not just use a startup script?

Comment: possible duplicate of [why windows service can't create folder when its started at windows welcome login page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11878239/why-windows-service-cant-create-folder-when-its-started-at-windows-welcome-logi)

Comment: Please don't repost your question. If you're not getting the answers you want, you need to consider *editing* your existing question.

Answer (score 0):

you haven't permission with your account, you must boot the service in a different ServiceAccount, try with the localSystem.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceaccount.aspx

Comment: right now, my service is localSystem, and I am wondering, why it is acting like that, even more than this, there is something really strange, there is a file exists, and when I do if(File.Exsit()), it gives me false !!